# Running bin/rails generate don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im following a rails tutorial, and when im supposed to run the command: 'bin/rails generate model Article'. An error occurs saying that there isnt such a command.

I'm using 'command prompt with ruby on rails' and in the rails project i can find a Bin folder. Am also using windows 7.

Also What is the difference between running only 'rails generate' instead of running 'bin/rails generate'?

Comment: Is it really that much of a difference using Ubtuntu?

Comment: Yea, especially if you plan on using rails for larger project or projects with certain dependencies. Windows doesnt play well with Ruby/Rails in some aspects.  Also if you plan to deploy Rails you might as well familiarize yourself with some **nix* OS now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rails generate` is fine if you have no bin stubs (binaries in the root `/bin` folder of your project). If you do have bin stubs then it's preferred to use them because they may do additional things specific to your project. But even then, it's (probably) fine to just use `rails generate` still. The other bin stubs may be a little more necessary to use, though (again, if present) because they tend to be shortcuts to e.g. `bundle exec rake`.

Rails 4.1 ships with bin stubs. That is, when you generate a Rails 4.1 project it generates bin stubs for you. So this is probably why your tutorial mentioned using them -- they're now there by default. But if you're on an older version of Rails that won't help you much.

The big reason Rails 4.1 includes bin stubs is because Rails uses [`spring`](https://github.com/rails/spring) by default now. Spring is an application preloader... that makes it so that when you call e.g. `bin/rake ...` it will load and keep a running rails environment in the background and then, the 2nd time you call `bin/rake` it will fork from the running environment giving you almost instantaneous response. So this is an example of "additional things specific to your project" that you get from using `bin/rake` over just `rake` and `bin/rails` over just `rails`.